# How to update some field data of foreginKey model? In Dagango Model

Tags: django, django-models

I have created 2 models, I want whenever I change the value or adding new value in the count_of_B field of ModelB, I want to add that value in the count_of_A field of ModelA.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    nameA = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    count_of_A = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class ModelB(models.Model):
    attached = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nameB = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    count_of_B = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mA = ModelA.objects.get(id=self.attached.id)
        mA.count_of_A += self.count_of_B
        mA.save()
        super(ModelB, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but when I ran some following syntax:

```
>>> from ForTesting.models import ModelA, ModelB
>>> ModelA.objects.all().delete()
(2, {'ForTesting.ModelB': 1, 'ForTesting.ModelA': 1})
>>> ModelB.objects.all().delete()
(0, {'ForTesting.ModelB': 0})
>>> mA=ModelA.objects.create(nameA="shiv", count_of_A=1)
>>> mB=ModelB.objects.create(nameB="shankar", count_of_B=1, attached=mA)
>>> print("A count: ", mA.count_of_A, "B count: ", mB.count_of_B)
A count:  1 B count:  1
>>> mB.count_of_B=4
>>> mB.save()
>>> print("A count: ", mA.count_of_A, "B count: ", mB.count_of_B)
A count:  1 B count:  4
```

I didn't get value change in the ModelA field. Is there anything wrong when I am defining save method in ModelB or I have to use post_save method for this kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it I am using same name mA,
when I used

```
print("A count: ", ModelA.objects.first().count_of_A, "B count: ", mB.count_of_B)
```

then got desire output:

```
A count:  6 B count:  4
```